# Phantomjs if proxy not respond

Tags: proxy, phantomjs

Script test.js:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = args[1];
page.open(url, function (status) {
    console.log(status); 
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Run script:

```
phantomjs --proxy=1.1.1.1:22 test.js 'http://nonexistent_site.com'
```

1.1.1.1:22 - nonexistent server

http://nonexistent_site.com - nonexistent site

How can I determine in PhantomJS which one is not responding - a proxy or a site?

Answer (score 2):

You can catch network timeouts with [page.onResourceTimeout](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) callback:

```
page.onResourceTimeout = function(request) {
    console.log('Response (#' + request.id + '): ' + JSON.stringify(request));
};
```

You can also set your own timeout:

```
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 3000; // ms
```

To intercept network errors you can register [page.onResourceError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html) callback:

```
page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
  console.log('Unable to load resource #' + resourceError.id + ' URL:' + resourceError.url);
  console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
};
```

With this in place, non-existent host will trigger `Host not found` error.

*But* if you use a non-working proxy, you will always end up with error `Network timeout on resource` first, even if target host does not exist.

So if you want to check proxies :) I'd suggest just to page.open hosts that are 100% working, for example, set up a simple static web page on the very server that you are operating from.

Also there is a node.js module: [proxy-checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxy-checker)

Comment: Thank you, it is true, but I thought that it is possible to check in phantom through the API proxy work.